# How do a table structure for questionnaires using MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

i'm currently working on a nutricional evaluation project and, i've come to a point, where i'm failing to see how to do some tables relationship.

What i want to do: The nutricionist can create questionnaires to facilitate his nutricional evaluation about his pacients. Others nutricionists would be allowed to use questionnaires that were created by other nutricionists.
(So these questionnaires would be public to use).

These questionnaires would have 5 to 10 questions tiped by the nutricionist, and the anwser for these questions would be a text tiped by the nutricionist as well.

Program Flow for New pacient: nutricionist register a new pacient(name, high, weight etc)  --> Nutricionist chooses or creates one or many questionnaire to help on his evaluation --> nutricionist asks the questions for his pacient --> nutricionist saves the pacient anwsers --> Program continues...

Program Flow for old pacient: Nutricionist finds pacient --> Nutricionist see the questionnaires related to that pacient (at this point, there could be questionnaires that were make by another nutricionist) --> Nutricionist can create a New questionnaire or see the questionnaires already related to that pacient (cannot erase or alter any questionnaire) --> Program continues....

Main question: how could i do the tables relationship​ of  nutricionist, questionnaire and pacient?
Create tables for the questions and awnsers? I'm seriously Lost.

Obs: English is not my native language, but o tried my best.

Comment: Probably would be useful to investigate how to normalize a database - this could be a possible starting point - 
 http://www.computerweekly.com/tutorial/Database-normalization-in-MySQL-Four-quick-and-easy-steps

Comment: Thanks, i'll start doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can create your tables in this format:

**1. Patient's Table**
Store details like the `id` *(unique value to search for the patient in another table, doing an `*AUTO_INCREMENT*` would be perfect)*, `name`, `weight`, `height`, etc

**2. Nutritionist's Table**
Store details like `id` *(unique value also)*, `name`, etc

**3. Questionnaire Table**
Store details like `id` *(same as others above)*, `patient_id`, `question`, `answer`, etc

For your program flow:

> Program Flow for New pacient: nutricionist register a new pacient(name, high, weight etc)
>
> > ***These Details will be entered into the `patient's` table***
>
> Nutricionist chooses or creates one or many questionnaire to help on his evaluation
>
> > ***These details will be stored or selected from the `questionnaire` table***
>
> nutricionist asks the questions for his pacient
>
> > ***These details will be FETCHED from the `questionnaire` table***
>
> nutricionist saves the pacient anwsers
>
> > ***These details will be saved (stored) in the `questionnaire` table***
>
> Nutricionist finds pacient
>
> > ***Select from `patients` table***
>
> Nutricionist see the questionnaires related to that pacient (at this point, there could be questionnaires that were make by another nutricionist)
>
> > ***Select from `questionnaire` table where the current patient id is equal to the one already stored in the table***
>
> Nutricionist can create a New questionnaire or see the questionnaires already related to that pacient (cannot erase or alter any questionnaire)
>
> > ***Insert into `questionnaire` table OR query from the `questionnaire` table***

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to know that my answer helped. Please 'accept' the answer if it has pointed you to the right direction OR an upvote if you still need more answers from other people. :)